# Extract buttons from PSD file for website

Tags: html, css, button, psd

I downloaded a PSD file containing buttons that i want to use on my website.  Problem is i don't know how to access them for use on the website. How would i extract these buttons? or is there a better way to do it? here is a screenshot of the psd open in photoshop.

[image: buttons]

Comment: is there a way to access the individual buttons with css?

Comment: Once you 'slice' the buttons in photoshop you will need to write the html and css for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Slicer application:

http://testslicer.codeborg.com:9080/

I tried it and it works perfect. You must upload .png file and then set the slice lines. You must have clicked on the layer if you want to slice it. Try it, it's really simple.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Nedoma's link and here is output:

First step: I crop your image nad add some lines

[image: Slicer]

Second: I used Split function

[image: Split function applied]

It looks there are more functions but they works only when you're using transparent background.

If you want to hide text layers before processing in this tool, there is link to Photoshop script http://slicer.codeborg.com/hide-text-script.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rectangular marquee tool, cut out the button you want, then create a image based off the button you just cut out. This will essentially give you the button you want, then in your website just have your button be that image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble saving the individual button images, you need to learn how to use the [slice tool](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&gs_nf=1&qe=cGhvdG9zaG9wIHNs&qesig=vjlw6EGv3J6jfKSVKv_hjA&pkc=AFgZ2tmofLwkLF_gNSv6wpnSuFCbbosz4znm7Ncv5Hh37tYfFUiIbJxGzKMdyJ7ZVxfXKHNmU5DVTTH9k6rOgfklY_sAB4jjhQ&cp=12&gs_id=1a&xhr=t&q=photoshop+slice+tool&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=photoshop+sl&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=89b2b796eed5d3ab&biw=1680&bih=914)